# Set Progressbar in the Center of WebView in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I want to set this progressbar in the center of Web view:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity = "center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

//this works fine for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The relevant fix is changing “gravity” to “layout_gravity” on the ProgressBar. By the way, you can take out the “layout_gravity” you put in on the FrameLayout itself—not sure what it’s doing there.

Comment: @LawrenceD'Oliveiro In a framelayout , I've a Button(text : Login, txt at center) and a progressbar(circle/spinning). How do I can set the progress bar to the right of the button text with some space between them? Do you have any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Maybe you don't see progress bar because it is white. Put bg there and you will see it is in the center.

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal ania's answers is also work if your place first webview and then progressbar.